# Rendering JFreeChart to PDF and Rectangle2D Import Confusion

Tags: java, itext, jfreechart

I am trying to render a timeline chart to a PDF file. Following various examples I need to create a Rectangle2D object.

```
import com.itextpdf.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

PdfTemplate tp=cb.createTemplate(width,height);
Graphics2D g2D=new PdfGraphics2D(cb,width,height);
Rectangle2D r2D=new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,width,height);
Chart.getInstance().getChart().draw(g2D,r2D);
```

My IDE (Eclipse Oxygen) does not like that and wants Rectangle2D from java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D instead. The 'draw' method is flagged with the error:

The method draw(java.awt.Graphics2D, java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D) in the type JFreeChart is not applicable for the arguments (java.awt.Graphics2D, com.itextpdf.awt.geom.Rectangle2D)

How do I resolve this? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an IDE issue. When I let Eclipse automatically add the import to use java.awt rather than com.itextpdf it resulted in an error when I tried to create the Rectangle2D object. This was why I thought the problem was with the chart.draw method. However, when I added the import for java.awt manually the error on Rectangle went away. The result was a error free compile but now I have an exception that I do not understand so I will create a new thread for that.